# Question about the implementation of std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, icmp_header& header)

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

I saw such an implementation for `asio::icmp_header` in `asio-1.22.1/src/examples/cpp03/icmp/icmp_header.hpp`

```
class icmp_header
{
   //omit several functions
   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, icmp_header& header)
    { return is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header.rep_), 8); }
   //omit several functions
private:
   unsigned char rep_[8];  //no other member variable, indeed
}
```

***Why not write the method like this***:

```
   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, icmp_header& header)
    { return is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header.rep_), sizeof(icmp_header)); }
```

You see `class icmp_header` is a simple class without any inheritance.

To avoid the unforeseen\uncertain padding on different operating systems?

Comment: I don't see how inheritance would change anything here?

Comment: @appleapple Sorry for my poor English.I mean things would be different if `icmp_header` is derived from a base class.

Comment: One could argue that repeating the size twice is not good style, but then it should use `sizeof(header.rep_)` instead, not `sizeof(icmp_header)`. And one could also argue that the size shouldn't be a "magic constant" either.

Comment: @user17732522 I almost fully understand you. "***repeating the size twice*** is not good style" What's that?

Comment: I just mean that you have the size twice. Once in `unsigned char rep_[8];` and once in `is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(header.rep_), 8)`. These two `8` should probably represent the exact same quantity, namely the length of the ICMP header. So it should be written explicitly only once, either as the size of the array or even better as a constant named something like `ICMP_HEADER_LENGTH` and then reused. That avoids accidentally mismatching the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the class definition in the header file that defines how large an ICMP header is, but it is the protocol definition. And from there it can be derived that the header is 8 octets (bytes). Therefore, it is reasonable to hard-code the size in the `read()` function call in order to ensure that exactly that many bytes are read.

That the size of the buffer in the class definition is *also* 8 characters, is just because to make it sufficiently large. Theoretically, the implementers could have chosen a larger size for the buffer, but that would not change the fact that the data stream has just 8 bytes dedicated for the header.

Answer (score 3):

The `read` call does not write into `header` but it writes to its member `header.rep_`. The member is a `unsigned char[8];` which is 8 bytes. And no padding of `header` will change that.
It would be different if the `read` would write directly to `header`. Then layout of `icmp_header` would matter.